# Vim - Auto complete without doing ctrl x + ctrl o

Tags: neovim, plugin-vim-go

I'm able to get the auto complete menu to come up with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>/<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> combos, but would like to have the window pop-up automatically. Is there a mapping that would enable this?

Comment: There is no mapping to make complete menu auto-popup. But there are numerous plugins that makes complete menu popup automatic, i.e it pops up when you type something.